# Play Framework cannot compile my class, showing me strange character in my stacktrace

Tags: java, playframework

I am developing a web application with Play! Framework using Notepad++ on windows xp. whenever I create new class, save and refresh the browser to see the changes, I get the following error:

The file /app/utils/NameUtil.java could not be compiled. Error raised is : The declared package "" does not match the expected package "utils")

In /app/utils/NameUtil.java (around line 1)

1:
 i↓mport java.util.*;

2:
 import models.*;
3:
 import java.lang.*;
4:
 import play.Logger;
5:
6:
 public class NameUtil {
7:

if you notice line 1, there is a strange charecter which is not visible in my text editor. I've tried to change my text format from utf-8 to ansi and from dos/windows to unix, but it's no use.

What is the problem exactly? and if it's encoding problem, shouldn't playframework support utf-8 formats?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that it's trying to use escape sequences to highlight the error, or something like that.

The correct fix for the compiler error itself is to following the compiler error, and add:

```
package utils;
```

as the first line of the file.

See whether you see the same kind of behaviour when you get other compiler errors. (You're about to get one due to your current first line of `import java.util;` - that should be `import java.util.*;` or a particular class within the `java.util` package, assuming that this is meant to be a normal Java file.)

As an aside, I haven't used the Play! framework myself, but is there any reason why you want to use Notepad++ rather than an IDE such as Netbeans, Eclipse or IntelliJ? Do they not play nicely with "Play!"?

Comment: Jon, the reason why a fully featured IDE is not often used for Play, is because it doesn't really need it. Play abstracts so much of the 'noise' of web application, making it possible to develop using simple editors. I myself use IntelliJ, just for the code completion side of things, but that is about it.

Comment: @Codemwnci: The code completion side is what I was thinking of, mostly - as well as having an editor which is able to highlight lines of invalid code more easily, etc. I'd also assume that most web applications are still going to need something other than a presentation layer - and at that point, surely you're going to be writing "normal" Java aren't you? Maybe I'm missing the point of the framework.

Comment: Aye, there is still normal Java, but there have been a number of design patterns employed within Play to just make it easier. Have a quick play around, or watch the demo on the framework homepage, and it will make a lot of sense.

Comment: The reason I am using a text editor is just to challenge myself, to see if I am capable to build a system without the IDE help. sometimes I do that with small java applications too. It also helps me to memorize the API.

Comment: Jon, play! fully supports Eclipse, netbeans and IntelliJ (Hey, it's just a java app we're talking about) it even have some helpers to automatically build the project for you (play eclipsify | netbeansify | idealize)... And even thought it is possible (and not so difficult) to work with notepad (play's author uses mate in a mac) I agree with you that a full fetured IDE is almost a must for java development...