# Playframework 2.1.1 cannot compile, because appear hide characters

Tags: playframework

These characters are not displayed in my notepad editor.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Play Framework cannot compile my class, showing me strange character in my stacktrace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562176/play-framework-cannot-compile-my-class-showing-me-strange-character-in-my-stack)

Comment: @Juhana Nope, not a duplicate. The question you linked is about someone forgetting fo declare a `package` for their class, this one is about wrong encoding (possibly UTF-8 with BOM).

Answer (score 0):

Just open the file in some editor capable of displaying hidden characters. You can use VI(M) for that, here you have a tutorial on how to do it: http://www.chrispian.com/quick-vi-tip-show-hidden-characters/

Otherwise just delete everything and start from scratch (don't copy-paste).